# dartanalyser marks error "[error] Target of URI does not exist"

Tags: dart, dart-pub

after running pub get to import the necessary packages into a ./packages folder, dartanalyser still doesn't find the packages imported.

After trying pub cache repair and checking to see if the imports are in the ./packages folder, the same error message is reported.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the folder for a file called .packages

Delete this file and run pub get again.